# Can I force change the DeviceFamily property in Windows 10, or enable DeviceFamilyOverride?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, registry

I searched. Found nothing. Apparently there's this thing called DeviceFamilyOverride but I can't find that either. Google Bard and ChatGPT lie, you can't find the DeviceFamily key in the registry. Any ways?

Well, doing this in a VM, AI is sketchy. Nothing happened. Nothing worked. So hope you can help.
Thanks!

Comment: DFO was in a deleted Twitter (well, now X).